# Android layout or button

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-tabhost

I'm having a problem with an Android APP that seems related to layout. Attached image you'll see that the "Alerts" button sticks out and doesn't seem the same as the other buttons. I've replaced the image with a known good one, but the problem remains.

[image: screenshot]

It was suggested it was because it is tabhost layout, but all the changes that have been recommended have not worked. So far I've tried changing the attributes from android:height and width to "wrap_content", "fill_parent", and "match_parent". Match caused another strange white space to be corrected, but this button is my last apparent challenge.

Here's the layout code, can you tell me what the problem is?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/job_tab_bar_search"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:freezesText="false"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:paddingLeft="17dp"
    android:text="Search"
    android:textColor="@color/color_text_default"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHistory"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/job_tab_bar_history"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:text="History"
    android:textColor="@color/color_text_default"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFavorites"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/job_tab_bar_favorites"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:text="Favorites"
    android:textColor="@color/color_text_default"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAlerts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/job_tab_bar_alerts"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:text="Alerts"
    android:textColor="@color/color_text_default"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.32" >
    </FrameLayout>
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TabWidget>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd think someone would have replied, in the end it was stupid simple.

The answers is:

Tabhost using tabactivity will display the background through menu items if they are re-sized. Add a color coded (html notation) color to the schema, then call that with the android:border-background construct.